# Is there a way to issue commands on a remote queue manager?

Tags: linux, ibm-mq

My app is running on a server with MQ Client installed. I want to issue create and delete queue commands on a queue manager running on a different server.

I know this is possible by issuing `runmqsc -w <remote_qmgr>` commands on a local queue manager, but we don't have a local queue manager running (only MQ Client).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MQ v8, then you can administer remote queue manager without the need of a local queue manager. Just the MQ Client installation is required. The `-c` option makes the runmqsc to connect to remote queue manager using a client connection.

```
runmqsc -c <remote qm>
```

You will need to set either `MQSERVER` or `MQCHLLIB and MQCHLTAB` environment variable for runmqsc to find the queue manager connection information.

More details [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083460_.htm)

You can also use MQ Explorer GUI to administer a remote queue manager.

Answer (score 0):

And if you're not yet on IBM MQ V8, then there are other tools out the that can allow you to issue MQSC commands on a client machine, for example my company's MQSCX tool.

You can also use GUI tools such as the MQ Explorer or my company's GUI Administrator tool, MO71 rather than command line MQSC commands if you prefer.